# Fetch the attribute value using attribute code in Model file

Tags: magento2.4.5, frontend-model

In 3rd party Plugin's Model file, i am trying to fetch attribute code and display the attribute value in Product View Page. But values are not fetching.

```
$valueAddition = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('making_charges_value')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

or

```
$valueAddition = $_product->getData($making_charges_value);
```

Here is [Full Function code](https://pastebin.com/f4NNnZqY) , [Full File code](https://pastebin.com/7wVJa5p9)

[image]

I restarted working on magento after many years, please consider me as fresher

Comment: ypu can try `$_product->getMakingChargesValue();` OR `$_product->getAttributeText(making_charges_value);`

Comment: @Pawan i updated the code, but the value is not displaying [in the website link](https://frontend1.staging.glowjewels.com/floral-glow-diamond-mangalsutra)

Comment: in that case, you need to update attribute in admin and make sure it is set YES, for `used in product listing`.

Comment: @Pawan i have updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code
from this :

```
$valueAddition = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('making_charges_value')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

To this :

```
$valueAddition = $mainProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('making_charges_value')->getFrontend()->getValue($mainProduct);
```

Comment: Did the issue resolve?

Comment: not yet solved ,

Answer (score 1):

You have applied the correct code.
Now please verify the attribute settings in the admin panel

Step 1
[image: Step 1]

Step 2
[image: Step 2]

Step 3
[image: Step 3]

Step 4
[image: Step 4]

Step 5
[image: step 5]